# Setting the rpath of an executable when building iwth ld

Tags: linux, linker, ld, linker-scripts

`ld` accepts an option `-rpath <path>` that appends the given path to the front of calculated rpath. How do I completely replace the rpath of a given executable? Does ld provide a linker script function (similar to `SEARCH_DIR`, `ENTRY`) that can be used to set the rpath?

Comment: You deleted your most recent question before I could post my comment.  In case you haven't figured out some mistake, posting it here:  argc is the first arg and definitely passed in EDI (low half of RDI).  If you're seeing something else in EDI, either your debugger is broken (ABI mismatch with the kernel's register struct, or similar debugger bug) or you didn't actually stop at the very first instruction of main.  Try single-stepping some code that does stuff like `mov edi, 1` / `mov esi, 2` and see if values show up in the correct registers to sanity-check your debugger.

Comment: @PeterCordes The problem was that `main` function was being invoked as `_start`. Values in registers were probably garbage and `%rsi` happened to contained the number of arguments.

Comment: Ah, yes that's correct.  The x86-64 SysV ABI defines the process-startup state that _start sees; it's not a function.  Registers hold garbage except for RSP and RDX (if non-null, a pointer to register with atexit).  In a statically linked executable where _start is the first thing that runs in user-space at all (instead of ld.so), Linux chooses to zero the registers to avoid leaking kernel data.